# Infinite image scroll right to left

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Infinite Scroll]

I'm trying to scroll my associates's logos right to left without buttons automatically.

There is my HTML code

```
<div class="associates">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/5.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/6.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/7.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/8.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/9.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/10.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="IMG/associate/11.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

How can I scroll them infinitely with Jquery?

Comment: And what have you tried? Tried any library?

Comment: have you tried html's  `<marquee>` tag?

Comment: @RajeshJangid It's deprecated, do not use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: I searched on google to do what i want via jquery but there was no answer. I'm looking for a code like marquee but via jquery. Because there is an issue on other browsers except Chrome. It jumps 10px-10px like low fps. I hope you got what i mean. sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good soluttion can be found here
[css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/)

It basically does the trick by animating an image layer with two identical areas and masking the overflow.
Elegant and usable.